# VBA Record date of row change in specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automatically update the "Updated" column of an excel spreadsheet when any cell of that specific row changes to today's date. I was able to do this by hard-coding where the "Updated" column header would be, however, it is now necessary to search for that column header as it may move.

The code I am trying to implement works but immediately gives me the error `Automation error - The object invoked has disconnected from it's clients.`

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:DX")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim f As Range

        Set f = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:DD1").Find("Updated", lookat:=xlWhole)
        ' f.Row = Range(Target).Row

        If Not f Is Nothing Then
           Range(Split(f.Address, "$")(1) & Target.Row).Value = Now
        Else
            MsgBox "'Updated' header not found!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got into an endless loop.
Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:DX")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim f As Range

        Set f = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:DD1").Find("Updated", lookat:=xlWhole)
        ' f.Row = Range(Target).Row

        If f Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "'Updated' header not found!"
        ElseIf Intersect(Target, f.EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(Target.EntireRow, f.EntireColumn).Value = Now
'        Else
'            MsgBox "We entered this function again because the row above updated the Updated column", vbInformation, "False alarm"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To understand what happens,

- Uncomment the else and MsgBox
- Put a breakpoint on the MsgBox
- When you hit it, press `[ctrl]-L`

Answer (score 0):

In a case such as this, I run into far fewer problems when I simply loop through the available cells to find the column header. Using the `.Find` method also works, but is less "tunable" to my needs in a custom application.

```vb
Public Function FindColumn(header As String) As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim headerCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VTO2 Labor")
    lastCol = sh.Cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    headerCol = 0
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        If sh.Cells(1, i).Value = header Then
            headerCol = i
        End If
    Next i
    FindColumn = headerCol
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear on whether the *Updated* column header *could* be in row 1 or if it will *always* be in row 1, just not in the same location.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:DX")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_SafeExit
        'TURN OFF EVENTS IF YOU ARE GOING TO WRITE A VALUE INTO THE WORKSHEET!
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim uCol As Long, f As Range
        If Application.CountIf(Rows(1), "updated") Then
            uCol = Application.Match("updated", Rows(1), 0)
            For Each f In Intersect(Target, Range("A:DX"))
                If f.Row > 1 Then _
                    Cells(f.Row, uCol) = Now
            Next f
        Else
            MsgBox "'Updated' header not found!"
        End If
    End If
bm_SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That should survive multiple updates (e.g. when pasting values). The problem I see is that is the Updated column is being shifted around, presumably through inserting columns or the like, then the change routine is going to run.