# Automatic date and time in cell if any of the preceding cells of the row have been modified

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2010

I want to add a column "last modified" to my excel sheet that automatically sets the date of the last update to any cells of the of the preceding columns of that row.

For example the column last modified will be in column AA. If any of cells of column A to Z have been modified change the date and time and keep that value, but don't change the date and time if another cell in another row is modified.

I have tried using this

=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$Z1;"<>")>0;NOW();"")

The problem is that when I modify a cell in row 6 for example the date in row 1 also changes.

How can I make it it only modifies the date if there is truly a change in the range as in the formula?

Comment: Events can be processed in VBA

Comment: See [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883870/vba-record-date-of-row-change-in-specific-column) or [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206598/update-date-cell-for-each-cell-change) for a few examples on how to use that change event for a date-recording of change. Notice the `Intersect` being used to clarify which columns/ranges are allowed to be looked before changing the dates.

Comment: An Excel spreadsheet does not maintain any state. So you cannot track changes using only Excel spreadsheet functions. You will need a VBA or an xll solution for this.